# How to use matlab to solve ordinary differential equations with coupled intermediate variables inside?

Tags: matlab, ode

I have a problem which can be simplified to the statement below (the real equations and functions are much more complicated):

System: `dot_X1 = -A*X1; dot_X2 = B*(X2-5) + u;`

dot_ means differentiate with time t, X1 and X2 are system states respectively, A and B are both intermediate variables, u is the system control input which can be a ramp or step input defined by myself.

I know how to use ode to solve normal similar problems when A and B and not coupled, for example, when A and B are only functions of X1, X2 and u respectively. But now in my problem, A and B are coupled, like:

`A = f(X1, X2, u, B), B = g(X1, X2, u, A),` f and g are very complicated functions.

Now in every time interval when solving the ode problem, for example, [0s, 0.01s], I have to calculate both A and B in order to use ode function in matlab. But since A and B are coupled and f and g are very complicated, I don't know how to deal with this.

Could you give me some help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You either need to solve this coupling as a system of non-linear equations using Newton's method or a pre-packaged solver of matlab.

Or you can consider the system as a system of differential-algebraic equations

```
(X1',X2') = F(t,(X1,X2),(A,B),u)
        0 = G(t,(X1,X2),(A,B),u)
```

and use the appropriate solver packages DASSL or DAEPACK or similar. See http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Differential-algebraic_equations